# Unable to get highest version of the TRADE in Perl

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I have just started learning Perl and got stuck in precarious scenario. Input Source XML FILE is:

```
<STATEMENT>
     <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="1",version="1">
      <EVENT type="PRO">
       <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MY"/>
       <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
      </EVENT>
     </TRADE>
     <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="1",version="2">
      <EVENT type="PRO">
       <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MYY"/>
       <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
      </EVENT>
     </TRADE>
     <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="2",version="1">
      <EVENT type="PRO">
       <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MY"/>
       <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
      </EVENT>
         <TRADE origin = "BANK" ref="1",version="1">
           <EVENT type="PRO">
              <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MY"/>
              <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
           </EVENT>
         </TRADE>
       </TRADE>
    <STATEMENT>
```

Now I need to filter Trades with following 'AND' conditions:

1. Only trades with origin = "BANK"
2. TRADE should have "type" attribute of `<EVENT>`  = 'PRO'
3. TRADE should have "key" attribute of `<EVENTNAR>` = "USE"
4. TRADE should have "value" attribute of `<EVENTNAR>` = "MY"
5. Multiple `<EVENTNAR>` can be there under  `<EVENT>` of a `<TRADE>`. At least one    `<EVENTNAR>` should be legitimate.
6. All sub-trades i.e TRADE inside TRADE should be deleted :
7. The most important of all - Only highest versionno for given ref can be   taken (this is not working)

Expected output:

```
 <STATEMENT>
      <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="1",version="2">(higher version)
        <EVENT type="PRO">
           <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MYY"/>
           <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
        </EVENT>
      </TRADE>
      <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="2",version="1">
        <EVENT type="PRO">
          <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MY"/>
          <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
        </EVENT>
      </TRADE>
    <STATEMENT>
```

Following is my code :

```
use strict;
  use warnings;
  use XML::Twig;
  use Tie::File;


    my $SOURCEFILE=$ARGV[0];
    my $FILELOCATIONIN=$ARGV[1];


    open( my $out, '>:utf8', 'out.xml') or die "cannot create output file out.xml: $!";


    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(  pretty_print => 'indented',
      twig_handlers => { 'TRADE'=>\&TRADE_HANDLER,
                            'TRADE/TRADE' => \&DEL_TRADE},
                         att_accessors => [ qw/ ref version / ],

     );

    my %max_version;

    $twig->parsefile($FILELOCATIONIN.'/'.$SOURCEFILE.'.xml');


    for my $trade ($twig->root->children('TRADE')) {
      my ($ref, $version) = ($trade->ref, $trade->version);
    if ($version eq $max_version{$ref})
    {
     $trade->flush($out);
    }

    }

    sub DEL_TRADE{
    my ( $twig, $TRADE ) = @_;
    $TRADE->delete($TRADE);
    #$twig->purge();
    }


    sub TRADE_HANDLER {
        my ( $twig, $trade ) = @_;

        my $org   = $trade->att('origin');


     if ($org eq "BANK"  &&  grep {grep {$_->att('key') eq 'USE' and $_->att('value') eq 'MY'}
        $_->children('EVENTNAR')} $trade->children('EVENT[@type="PRO"]') )

    {
        my ($ref, $version) = ($trade->ref, $trade->version);

        unless (exists $max_version{$ref} and $max_version{$ref} >= $version) {
        $max_version{$ref} = $version;}

    }

    else
    {
    $twig->purge();
    }

    return ;
    }
```

My output is:

```
<STATEMENT>
      <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="1",version="1">(this shouldn't come )
         <EVENT type="PRO">
          <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MY"/>
          <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
         </EVENT>
       </TRADE>
       <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="1",version="2">
        <EVENT type="PRO">
          <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MYY"/>
          <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
         </EVENT>
       </TRADE>
    <TRADE origin = "BANK", ref="2",version="1">
        <EVENT type="PRO">
          <EVENTNAR key = "USE" val = "MY"/>
          <EVENTNAR key = "USEE" val = "MYY"/>
        </EVENT>
      </TRADE>
     </STATEMENT>
```

As can be seen, logic of highest version for given ref is not working.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your `xml` is not well-formed. There cannot be commas between attributes and you forgot to close `<STATEMENT>`.

Comment: The higher version trade doesn't comply to the condition 4.

Comment: What happens if multiple `TRADE` elements have the highest version number?

Comment: @borodin -In that case all the TRADES will be there...

Comment: @choroba--It comlies..If you see one set of EVENTNAR is right...That is sufficient for the TRADE to be selected

Comment: @karanarora: Someone fixed the data. In your original post, no EVENTNAR was "right".

Comment: @choroba sorry for that Sir, BUt can you please suggest some tweak in my code, so that it can work...banging my head since yesterday...Only highest version part is not working...rest all conditions are working..

Comment: @borodin - when I say all the trades I mean all the highest version TRADES..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), after fixing the input:

```
open file.xml ;
rm //TRADE/TRADE ;
$l = //TRADE[@origin='BANK'][EVENT[@type='PRO'][EVENTNAR[@key='USE'][@val='MY']]] ;
$h := hash @ref $l ;
for my $ref in { keys %$h } {
    $trades = xsh:lookup('h', $ref);
    ls $trades[@version=xsh:max($trades/@version)] ;
} | cat > output1.xml ;
```

For very large files, you can try the streaming interface:

```
$h = { {} } ;
stream :f file.xml :F /dev/null select TRADE {
    rm TRADE ;
    if (@origin='BANK'
        and EVENT[@type='PRO'][EVENTNAR[@key='USE'][@val='MY']]
       ) {
        $ref = @ref ;
        $record = xsh:lookup('h', $ref)/@version ;
        perl { $record ||= -1 } ;
        if (@version > $record) {
            $here = . ;
            perl { $h->{$ref} = $here } ;
        }
    }
} ;

create STATEMENT ;
for my $trade in { values %$h } mv $trade into STATEMENT ;
save :f output2.xml ;
```

On MSWin, you have to use `NUL` instead of `/dev/null`. The program can still be memory hungry - it needs to remember the whole output. If it's too much, you have to change it to process the file twice: in the first run, it'll remember the maximal version for each ref, in the second run, it will output.

```
$h = { {} } ;
stream :f file.xml :F /dev/null select TRADE {
    rm TRADE ;
    if (@origin='BANK' 
        and EVENT[@type='PRO'][EVENTNAR[@key='USE'][@val='MY']]
    ) {
        $ref = @ref ;
        $record = xsh:lookup('h', $ref) ;
        perl { $record ||= -1 } ;
        if (@version > $record) {
            $record = @version ;
            perl { $h->{$ref} = $record } ;
        }
    }
} ;

stream :f file.xml :F output3.xml select TRADE {
    rm TRADE ;
    if not(@origin = 'BANK'
           and EVENT[@type='PRO'][EVENTNAR[@key='USE'][@val='MY']]
           and xsh:lookup('h', @ref) = @version
    ) rm . ;
} ;
```

If the version + ref combinations are unique, you can simplify the condition in the last `if not`.

Comment: according to the OP's previous question, the file may be very big. Would this need to load the entire file in memory?

Comment: @mirod: Unfortunatelly, yes. I can think of a solution using the streaming interface later :-)

Comment: @mirod: here you are.

Comment: @karanarora: The algorithm should be similar. You have to process the whole file to get the maximums or solutions per ref.